# set column values based on subseries condition from another column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, counter

I am quite new on pandas so I found some difficulty. I hope in someone give me help. I have a dataset like this:

I'd like to set `'r'` column values as in the desired output. Every time `'r'` shows 1 subsequent values of `'r'` have to be set on 2 if column `'d'` got values not equal to None (alternatively other null value). Take a look at the desired output. I attempted several approaches but neither seems to work.

The original dataframe:

```
        r       d  
0       1       None  
1       None    -4  
2       None    -1  
3       None    -2  
4       None    -3  
5       None    -1  
6       None    -2  
7       None  None  
8       None  None  
9       None    -3  
10      None    -2  
11      None    -1  
12      None    -3
13      1     None 
14      None    -5
15      None    -7
```

The desired dataframe:

```
        r       d  
0       1       None  
1       2       -4  
2       2       -1  
3       2       -2  
4       2       -3  
5       2       -1  
6       2       -2  
7       None  None  
8       None  None  
9       None    -3  
10      None    -2  
11      None    -1  
12      None    -3
13      1     None 
14      2       -5
15      2       -7
```

Comment: Hi @DOc! Logic behind this transformation is a little entangled, colud you edit a question and reveal it?

Comment: Hi at all, @MikhailStepanov, yeap it's quite tricky. Every time I found r = '1' the next row values for 'r' need to be changed in 2. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'r': [1, *[np.NaN for _ in range(1, 12)]],
        'd': [-4, -1, -2, -3, -1, -2, np.NaN, np.NaN, -3, -2, -1, -3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.r[df.d.notnull()] = 2
print(df)
```

Result

```
      r    d
0   2.0 -4.0
1   2.0 -1.0
2   2.0 -2.0
3   2.0 -3.0
4   2.0 -1.0
5   2.0 -2.0
6   NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN
8   2.0 -3.0
9   2.0 -2.0
10  2.0 -1.0
11  2.0 -3.0
```

Is this what you are looking for? Your desired output seems odd.

Comment: Hi! in reality, the r=1 value should remain...thanks!

Comment: @DOc Oh, I see now. You changed your answer. I'll fix my code later.